# Most efficient way to place hundreds of array formulas?

Tags: excel, vba, formulas

I am new to VBA and advanced formulas for that matter and would deeply appreciate some guidance here.

I have a workbook that acts as a GUI for a database in another workbook. I use the following array formula to act as a search function:

```
{=IF(ISERROR(INDEX('Client Contact Database.xlsx'!Data.ContactsFull,SMALL(IF('Client Contact Database.xlsx'!Data.ContactClients=$L$1,ROW('Client Contact Database.xlsx'!Data.ContactClients)),ROW(1:1)),2)),"",INDEX('Client Contact Database.xlsx'!Data.ContactsFull,SMALL(IF('Client Contact Database.xlsx'!Data.ContactClients=$L$1,ROW('Client Contact Database.xlsx'!Data.ContactClients)-1),ROW(1:1)),1))}
```

Although very sloppy, this works fine. However, I now need to add option buttons to toggle between searching for two different things. This means I have to replace the array formula from A3:L104 through VBA. My question is twofold:

1. How can I shorten this formula to under 255 chars to use with .FormulaArray? I tried putting it in two halves but my understanding of syntax is not sufficient.
2. Even if I got that to work, I imagine it would be extremely slow and inefficient. Is there a better way to go about this task?

Any help is greatly appreciated, I'm in way over my head with this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First off, swap out your `IF(ISERROR(<formula>), "", <formula>)` for something that uses the [IFERROR function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IFERROR-function-F59BACDC-78BD-4924-91DF-A869D0B08CD5). This will effectively cut your formula in half as IFERROR takes care of error control and default value without duplicating the formula.

```
=iferror(INDEX('Client Contact Database.xlsx'!Data.ContactsFull,SMALL(IF('Client Contact Database.xlsx'!Data.ContactClients=$L$1,ROW('Client Contact Database.xlsx'!Data.ContactClients)-1),ROW(1:1)),1), "")
```

I did not build all of the external references and named ranges for a full build environment, but I believe I transcribed that correctly.

Comment: Thank you very much, this has the exact same effect as my old formula. Now the character count is below 255, however I still get the 1004 error. The line is as follows:
.
.

`Range("A3").FormulaArray = "=IFERROR(INDEX('Client Contact Database.xlsx'!Data.ContactsFull,SMALL(IF('Client Contact Database.xlsx'!Data.ContactClients=$L$1,ROW('Client Contact Database.xlsx'!Data.ContactClients)-1),ROW(1:1)),1), "")"`
.

Comment: Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It seems that I will have to build a full test environment in order to locate your problem. Am I correct in assuming that `ContactsFull` and `ContactClients` are named ranges with worksheet (not workbook) scope on the external Data worksheet found in [Client Contact Database.xlsx]? Can yo provide some sample data together with expected results (in your original question at the top of this page through edit)?